# Defining a pixel neighborhood in an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, algorithms, matrix

I am working with matrix operations in MATLAB, and I would have the following problem. I have matrix containing zero elements:

```
a=zeros(100,100)
```

and another matrix with significantly smaller dimension containing value 6:

```
b=6*ones(3,3)
```

I define some coordinates in matrix `a`: `a(45,50)`. I also consider this point as center of matrix  `b(2,2)`. I need to copy to matrix `a` the elements from matrix `b`, whose center  is defined by `b(2,2)`. I just know that it can be done manually by defining coordinates in matrix `a`. Please, is there any way, or inbuilt MATLAB function how to do it automatically? I am just MATLAB beginner.

Comment: Are there additional details you would share to help improve answers?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the display, the following works as long as you are doing right: you do not try to copy `b` values outside of `a`, because you did not specify what should be done when you are at `a(100,100)`. My choice is a circular shift, with a toroidal topology.

```
% a = zeros(100); aX = 45 ; aY = 50; 
a = zeros(12); aCenter = [4 6];
b = 6 * ones(3); bCenter = ceil(size(b)/2);

a(circshift(padarray(true(size(b)),size(a)-size(b),'post'),aCenter-bCenter))=b;
```

Basically, this creates a 2D logical indexing of `b` of the same size as `a`, with ones in the top left:

```
padarray(true(size(b)),size(a)-size(b),'post')
```

then `circshift` moves this pattern by the vector `aCenter-bCenter`:

```
circshift(...)
```

Finally, the elements of `a` with the above logical indexing are affected with the values in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using the sparse function, which allows you to construct matrices by supplying a list of non-zero indices. Here is a short example. Note that I have formatted the local blocks to show the matrix structure, even though they are represented as vectors.

```
% Define i indices in local coordinates
i = [-1,  0,  1,...
     -1   0   1,...
     -1   0   1];
% Define j indices in local coordinates
j = [ 1,  1,  1,...
      0   0   0,...
     -1  -1  -1];
% Construct 100 x 100 sparse matrix by using offsets
a = sparse(i + 45, j + 50, 6, 100, 100);
% Show subset of matrix
full(a(43:47, 48:52))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response, but, unfortunately, I would need to make it without using of sparse matrix. Please, is there any way how to make it with using common matrix format (zeros (100,100))? Thank you very much.